JavaScript Canvas arc drawing behaves inconsistently
I'm struggling to have arcs drawn on a canvas as, to my eyes, the method context.arc appears to behave differently than what the specifications claim (or I understood from them).
Following is a piece of code I'm using to draw:

A small dotted circle centered at the same coordinates the arc needs to be centered,
An arc to cover 45 degrees (it does not!!)

In the picture included (after the code) the console part shows the printouts of the used values for the arc function.
    l_Context.moveTo(l_Arc_Center_X, l_Arc_Center_Y) ;
    l_Context.beginPath();
    l_Context.setLineDash([2,2])
    l_Context.arc(l_Arc_Center_X, l_Arc_Center_Y, 5 , 0 , 2 * G_PI , true);
    l_Context.stroke();
    l_Context.closePath() ;
    
    l_Context.beginPath();
    l_Context.setLineDash([])
    console.log("l_Arc_Center_X                          : " + l_Arc_Center_X)
    console.log("l_Arc_Center_Y                          : " + l_Arc_Center_Y)
    console.log("p_Radius [cm]                           : " + p_Radius      )
    console.log("l_Start_Angle                           : " + l_Start_Angle )
    console.log("F_Convert_Degrees_to_Rads(l_Start_Angle): " + F_Convert_Degrees_to_Rads(l_Start_Angle))
    console.log("l_End_Angle                             : " + l_End_Angle)
    console.log("F_Convert_Degrees_to_Rads(l_End_Angle)  : " + F_Convert_Degrees_to_Rads(l_End_Angle))
    console.log("l_CCW                                   : " + l_CCW)

    l_Context.arc(l_Arc_Center_X, l_Arc_Center_Y, F_Convert_Lengh_from_cm_to_Map(p_Radius) , F_Convert_Degrees_to_Rads(l_Start_Angle) , F_Convert_Degrees_to_Rads(l_End_Angle) , l_CCW);
    l_Context.stroke();
    l_Context.closePath() ;

Note: Functions like F_Convert_Degrees_to_Rads are used to convert from metric dimensions and degrees to canvas values.
As the code shows, I'm drawing a small dotted circle whose center coincides with that of the arc I'm attempting to draw.
The following picture shows the result along with the console where the values of the parameters (to the "arc" function) are presented.

So, instead of getting a 45 degrees arc (from 45 to 90 degrees) I'm getting what remains to complete a whole circle and at the wrong angles (i.e. the complement of what I wish).
What am I doing wrong?
EDIT:
Thanks to @tricot's comments, my mistake became clear: Though I was taking into account the fact that the Y-axis points downwards when computing coordinates, I misunderstood the specifications of the arc function and did not properly convert the normal cartesian angles (meaning, the one that would be used if the origin would be at the bottom-left of the canvas) to the applicable value (meaning, 360 - angle).
Once I changed the computation of the angle as shown above, things do work as I need and in compliance to the specification.
There is one thing I fail to understand: Why the implementation is taking the top-left of the canvas as origin instead of adhering to normal geometry standards? I cannot see/imagine any reasonable justification for such deviation.
Thanks to all those that commented and helped me to understand my mistake.

Unless I'm missing the point: You're passing in true for the counter clock-wise parameter (MDN Docs), so the line travels the long way around.

Hi DBS and thanks for your comment. Yes, the CCW s true as the arc goes from 45 to 90 degrees. I tried to pass the start and end angle parameters exchanged in their position with no success.

"as the arc goes from 45 to 90 degrees": it will do that irrespective of the CCW boolean. The CCW boolean determines whether the line is drawn going counter-clockwise or clockwise, but in either case it will draw starting at 45° and ending at 90°. The output you see is consistent with a counter-clockwise draw process that starts at 45°. Note that the Y axis points downwards, so 45° is south-east of the center. Going counter-clockwise from there means passing east, north, west and finally ending in the south (90°). Just set CCW to false to get the inverse.

I think you just put the finger on my mistake... I forgot that Y points downwards (I can't imagine why this is the implementation as it makes things considerably more complex). I'll try simply to use (360 - angle) and see what I get. Thanks for you hint. Will post another message with the results when I'm done.

It's quite unclear what you were expecting exactly. You just said it's not what you observed, but failing to know what you did expected all we can do is repeat what the specs (or docs) say about it, which will just describe what you observed and thus might not be that useful to you.

@Kaiido, I forgot the fact that Y points downwards ana as such, 45 degrees would point NE and not SE. I didn't try as yet implementing the fix I mentioned in a previous comment so I don't know if it fix my problem. If it does, will post the fix here.

45deg points SE. The angles are based on the ellipse's major-axis, itself based on the rotation of the ellipse, based on the x-axis. Since here the ellipse is a circle drawn from arc its rotation is zero, which means both the start and end angles are based on the x-axis. So 0deg is E, 45deg is SE, 90deg is S. Then couter-clock-wise is quite literral, not sure how to get that wrong. There would be edge cases where the sum of both angles is bigger than 2PI, but it's not your case, so once again, I'm not sure what you were expecting and how to explain to you any better than the specs or docs.

@Kaiido, after @trincot's comment, I realized that my mistake was ignoring the fact that the y-axis points downwards when setting the angles of the arc as well as the use of the CCW flag. I just changed the computation of the angles from normal cartesian method by computing the angles as 360 - [normal cartesian angle] (and converted to radians) and now the arcs are drawn as needed.

@Kaiido, it is not clear to me why you refer to elliptical shapes. Any elliptical shape requires two "focuses" and the arc function receives only one (X and Y).

Because the arc(cx, cy, r, s, e, ccw) method is a shortcut for ellipse(cx, cy, r, r, 0, s, e, ccw). Given you state the behavior doesn't match you understanding of the specs, I thought you at least read it.

And regarding the coordinate system of the canvas, while I don't quite understand the link with your issue here, it's just one of the standards in computer graphics to have {10, 10}  correspond to the pixel at the 10th row 10th column from top-left. Sure there are other standards, but given all of CSS and SVG were already using that standard, it only makes sense the canvas2D API also uses this one.

@Kaiido, as for the ellipse, you need two focus points, not one. Having only one would yield a circle. As for the pixels counting, I believe that counting pixels on screen and coordinates on a drawable area, meaning a canvas, could be considered as two separate scenarios. While I understand that the standard is as you described, I believe that making a differentiation between the two cases would had been a more intuitive approach. I also believe that it is not only OK but a good idea to question things as it may sometimes trigger new ideas and eventually improvements.

There are 2 radii in the ellipse signature. A circle is just a particular ellipse and hence it makes sense we define arc as being a shortcut to ellipse: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-arc (disclaimer, I authored a big part of the current algo there). Yes, it's good to question things, nobody argued against that. Note that for it to be useful though you should try to understand why the current state is as it is, then try to check if your questions hadn't already been asked before (they've been). But the issue here is anyway unrelated:

you stated that the implementation doesn't behave as your understanding of the specs, but you still haven't stated what should happen per this understanding (and you apparently didn't even read those specs...)

Dear @Kaiido, I did read the specifications as well as few examples. One of those examples made me think (probably my mistake) that angles go from the positive x-axis and up (i.e. NE). Trincot's comment made me realizer of my mistake and, after fixing my code, the behavior does match the specs. As per ellipse/circle, a circle is a particular case of an ellipse when the two focus point are at the same coordinates and the two radii are the same size. The particularity of an ellipse is that the sum of the distances between any point on the ellipse and the two focus points is a constant.

@Kaiido (continued...) You may wish to check the definition of ellipses here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipse
